# PHP strip_tags not allowing less than '<' in string

Tags: php, strip-tags

Please let me know how to allow less than character '<' in `strip_tags()`

Code Snippet

```
$string ="abc<123";
StringFromUser($string);

function StringFromUser($string)
{

    if (is_string($string))
    {
        return strip_tags($string);

    }

}
```

Output : abc

Expected output abc<123

Comment: Why are you using `strip_tags` to begin with? Especially if it does not produce the desired result.

Comment: The answer is to not use strip_tags()

Comment: you misunderstood the function `strip_tags`. Read its manual.

Comment: If what you want to do is prevent users from submitting dangerous data, you should consider letting them submit whatever they want and instead use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) on the string when appending it to the generated HTML. This way, you can keep everything the user sends, without being in any danger.

Comment: < is a tag. It is being stripped. That is the purpose of the strip_tags function. If you don't want your tags to be stripped I recommend not using the strip_tags function.

Comment: @Mr_Chimp, technically, `<` is not a tag. But this case is covered by [the manual](http://php.net/strip_tags) with a warning: "Because `strip_tags()` does not actually validate the HTML, partial or broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected."

Comment: @rid +1 Fair point. I just can't resist a good snark on a Monday morning!

Answer (score 1):

Encode it properly in the first place.

```
$string ="abc&lt;123";
```

Although if you're not sanitizing for HTML output you shouldn't be using `strip_tags()` anyway.

Comment: I have an HTML form which takes the username and password from the user and then the function   function StringFromUser() is called   StringFromUser($string)
{

    if (is_string($string))
    {
        return strip_tags($string);

    }

}

Comment: Why would you *ever* use `strip_tags()` on *those*?

Comment: @tarun - So, site users are required to type their username and password using HTML code? What's that, a funny captcha?

Comment: My question is can we somehow allow '<' character while passing string to strip_tags. I read the following signature in PHP manual string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )  how should we pass '<' in $allowable tags

Comment: No, **you cannot do the right thing while doing the wrong thing.**

Comment: Thanks guys. I am newbie in PHP so now  if I use this is it fine
  
$username = StringFromUser(strval($_POST['username']));
  $password = StringFromUser(strval($_POST['password']));

function StringFromUser($string)
{

    if (is_string($string))
    {
        return htmlspecialchars($string);

    }

}

Answer (score 1):

`strip_tags` is a pretty basic and not very good way to *sanitize* data (i.e. "punch arbitrary values into shape"). Again, it's not a very good function, as you are seeing. You should only sanitize data if you have a very good reason to, oftentimes there is no good reason. Ask yourself what you are gaining from arbitrarily stripping out parts of a value.

You either want to *validate* or *escape* to avoid syntax problems and/or injection attacks. Sanitization is rarely the right thing to do. Read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) for more background on the whole topic.

Answer (score 0):

You could search for a character in your string, take it out, strip_tags() your string and put the character back in:

```
$string = "abc<123";
$character = "<";
$pos = strpos($string,$character);
$tag = ">";
$check = strpos($string,$tag);
if ($pos !== false && $check == false) {
    $string_array = explode("<",$string);
    $string = $string_array[0];
    $string .= $string_array[1];
    $string = strip_tags($string);
    $length = strlen($string);
    $substr = substr($string, 0, $pos);
    $substr .= "<";
    $substr .= substr($string, $pos, $length);

    $string = $substr;
} else {
    $string = strip_tags($string);
}
```

or you could use preg_replace() to replace all the characters you don't want to have in your $string.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem:**
The purpose to use trip_tags is to prevent attacking from HTML or PHP injection. However, trip_tags not only removes HTML and PHP tags, it also removes part of a math expression with a < operator. So, what we see is "abc<123" being replaced to "abc".

**The solution:**
What we know is a < followed by a space is not identified as HTML or PHP tags by strip_tags. So what I do is to replace "abc<123" to "abc< myUniqueID123". Please note there is a space followed the < sign. And also, only numbers followed the < sign are replaced. Next, strip_tags the string. Finally, replace "abc< myUniqueID123" back to "abc<123".

```
$string = "abc<123";
echo StringFromUser($string);

function StringFromUser($string)
{
    if (is_string($string)) {
        //change "abc<123" to "abc< myUniqueID123", so math expressions are not stripped.
        //use myQuniqueID to identity what we have changed later.
        $string = preg_replace("/(<)(\d)/", "$1 myUniqueID$2", $string);
        $string = strip_tags($string);
        //change "abc< myUniqueID123" back to "abc<123"
        $string = preg_replace("/(<) myUniqueID(\d)/", "$1$2", $string);
        return $string;
    }
}
```